# line-wrapping without affecting math equations

Tags: wrapping

Consider we have a long paragraph in a `.tex` file that includes displayed-math formula. For example

```
This is a long paragraph that includes many sentences with a few math equations. 
For example, this is the Einstein mass-energy formula
\begin{equation}
E=mC^2,
\end{equation}
while this one is the Newton's second law:
\begin{equation}
F=ma.
\end{equation} 
We can add a few more sentences but I think it is in a good shape by now.
```

Using `vim`, I want to wrap the lines of the whole paragraph (not one line at a time) without wrapping the displayed math equations. Is it possible? I tried `gqip` but it wraps the equations, as well.

P.S.: I know that `gqip` does not wrap "citations". For example, if there is a

```
\cite{reference1,reference2,reference3,reference4,reference5,reference6}
```

in the paragraph then it will not be wrapped by `gqip`. I am actually looking for something like this.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Comment: I've not had any luck with this in the past, but [this question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/21272/4655) seems to be loosely related. Otherwise, if you're comfortable giving up all of your formatting to an external tool, there are solutions on [LaTeX code sniffer and/or beautifier?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/26102/88563) and the linked questions.

Answer (score 2):

[latexindent.pl](https://latexindentpl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/sec-default-user-local.html) does a very good job at this.

You can configure it by setting `:set formatprg=latexindent\ -m\ -l\ myWrapOptions.yaml\ -` with

```
# myWrapOptions.yaml
modifyLineBreaks:
    textWrapOptions:
        columns: 40
noIndentBlock:
    mathEnvironment:
      begin: '\\begin\{equation\*?\}'
      end: '\\end\{equation\*?\}'
```

This is the output using your example with a slightly longer equation:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
This is a long paragraph that includes
many sentences with a few math
equations. For example, this is the
Einstein mass-energy formula
\begin{equation}
E=mC^2,
\end{equation}
while this is the wave equation
\begin{equation}
    \nabla^2 \textbf{E} = \mu \epsilon \frac{\partial^2 \textbf{E}}{\partial t^2}
\end{equation}
We can add a few more sentences but I
think it is in a good shape by now.
\end{document}
```

For a more ad-hoc solution, `latexindent` won't touch blocks surrounded by `% \begin{noindent}` and `% \end{noindent}`. However, since you probably want to change the default wrapping options, this is probably unnecessary.

Comment: Interesting! Thanks for sharing :)